# Job application in UK: using US style resume or not

Tags: resume, applications, united-kingdom

I am planning to apply for jobs in UK (hopefully London). I am currently working as a data scientist in the US. Should I change the style of my resume to UK CV style? Or, should I apply with the same resume as I have used in US?

My US resume is a single page & two column, color resume. However, UK resumes seems to be longer and black&white.

One argument is that it is better to follow the style of job market you are applying to, so I should change my resume to UK style CV. But some of my friends argue that my US style resume can be considered as *interesting* in UK job market, and hence increaase my chance of landing a job there. I am confused, what would you suggest?

Background: I am a citizen of a south american country, and I hold a PhD from a US university.

Comment: What's the difference between the styles?

Comment: Thanks Emil. My US resume is a single page & two column color resume. However, UK resumes seems to be longer and black&white. 
You can learn more if you google "US resume vs UK CV".

Comment: Personally I would try to conform to the standards of the market you are trying to enter. These things get read very quickly by busy people and usually they are looking for specific information in the first instance, standing out because of colour or such is seldom a good thing unless possibly you are working in prepress, stand out by what you have achieved instead. Also, assume they will be printed black and white and on A4 paper (Not letter!), and make sure this works and renders reasonably, especially important if sending a word document.

Comment: I agree with the answers that you should tailor what you send for the market you're applying in, but I'd add that you might find the more verbose CV format less restrictive.  If you hold a PhD, likely you have publications and have attended more than 1 university, plus you're currently holding a job in the US.  The extra room might let you include potentially relevant information that doesn't make the cut for a single page resume.

Answer (score 6):

> My US resume is a single page & two column, color resume. However, UK
>   resumes seems to be longer and black&white.

I  would argue that your "US resume" is rather unusual.

In over 30 years as a hiring manager in the US, I can't recall ever receiving any one-page, two-column, color resumes. Maybe I did, but none that were memorable enough to remember.

Either way, produce a resume that is more normal for the locale in which you would like to work. Your background and abilities should make you stand out - not the "interesting" formatting of your resume.

Answer (score 5):

If you are applying for a job in the UK, I would strongly suggest using a UK CV format. It will be perceived as more professional, and help recruiters and employers to skim through it more efficiently.
These people read dozens of CV's every day; if they can't find the information they're looking for quickly, they might just skip it and move to the next candidate.

Beside the format, here are some general tips to keep in mind:

- Keep your CV brief and concise; Avoid long, elaborate descriptions.
- Include only information that is relevant to the role you're looking for.
- Be factual and describe things you did, rather than opinions you have.
- Avoid self flattery and personal opinions. This is especially relevant to your skills; how many people brand themselves as a 'Problem Solver', 'Peoples Person' or 'Natural Leader'. You'll have a chance to make that impression during the interview

Finally, I wish you all the best in finding a good job in the UK. I just made the move to the UK two years ago, and there are definitely a lot of great professional opportunities in the country.